# Como somar colunas de tabelas diferentes?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando montar um comando SQL para minha loja virtual que retorna o valor total do pedido, uma tabela de itens (pedidoitemaux) e outra de adicionais para os itens (pedidoitemadaux). Montei um comando, porém está ocorrendo o erro no Mysql:

> Every derived table must have its own alias.

Segue o comando SQL:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Total_P + Total_A) AS Total
FROM
    (SELECT 
        Pi.IdItem,
            SUM(Pi.Quantidade * Pi.ValorUnit) AS Total_P,
            0 AS Total_A
    FROM
        pedidoitemaux Pi
    GROUP BY Pi.IdItem UNION ALL SELECT 
        Pa.IdItem,
            0 AS Total_P,
            SUM(Pa.Quantidadead * Pa.Valorad) AS TotalA
    FROM
        pedidoitemadaux Pa
    GROUP BY Pa.IdItem)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pela mensagem de erro, só está pedindo um alias para a tabela derivada:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(x.Total_P + x.Total_A) AS Total
FROM
    (SELECT 
        Pi.IdItem,
        SUM(Pi.Quantidade * Pi.ValorUnit) AS Total_P,
        0 AS Total_A
    FROM
        pedidoitemaux Pi
    GROUP BY Pi.IdItem 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
       Pa.IdItem,
       0 AS Total_P,
       SUM(Pa.Quantidadead * Pa.Valorad) AS TotalA
    FROM
        pedidoitemadaux Pa
    GROUP BY Pa.IdItem) x
```

Comment: Perfeito, Rovann. Deu certo! Muito obrigado, me ajudou muito.