# Como fazer uma soma entre duas tabelas com um campo?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gostaria de somar esses dois selects.

Sei que dá para colocar em variáveis mas não sei como fazer.

Acredito que tenha isso na internet, mas não soube pesquisar direito.

```
SELECT (SUM(QTY)*-1) AS QUANTIDADE_SAIDA
FROM OUTGOINGS
WHERE ITEMID = 8
GROUP BY ITEMID

SELECT sum(qty) as Quantidade_Entrada
FROM incomings
WHERE itemId = 8
GROUP BY itemId
```

[image: Consulta do código acima]

Comment: Eu faria um union select (QUANTIDADE_SAIDA + Quantidade_Entrada) as qtd_total
from
(
SELECT (SUM(QTY)*-1) AS QUANTIDADE_SAIDA , 0 Quantidade_Entrada
FROM OUTGOINGS 
WHERE ITEMID = 8 
GROUP BY ITEMID 
union all
SELECT 0 as Quantidade_Entrada, sum(qty) as Quantidade_Entrada 
FROM incomings 
WHERE itemId = 8 
GROUP BY itemId
) tvirtual

Comment: Daria para generalizar e agrupar por ITEMID tb

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: @Motta, tentei fazer com union e não consegui por não ser familiarizado com ele.
Mas irei pesquisar sobre.
Como faço para generalizar o itemID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--generalizando o comentário

--solução por union all

--uma das possíveis

```
select itemId,(QUANTIDADE_SAIDA + Quantidade_Entrada) as qtd_total 
 from 
 ( SELECT itemId,(SUM(QTY)*-1) AS QUANTIDADE_SAIDA , 0 Quantidade_Entrada 
   FROM OUTGOINGS 
   GROUP BY ITEMID 
   union all 
   SELECT itemId,0 as Quantidade_Entrada, sum(qty) as Quantidade_Entrada 
   FROM incomings 
   GROUP BY itemId ) tvirtual 
  where itemId in (7,8,9);
```

[Doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Achei nesse post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/256930/como-somar-colunas-de-tabelas-diferentes. 

Muito parecido com o seu. Muito Obrigado Motta

Answer (score -2):

Não seria:

```
SELECT out.QTY + inc.QTY
FROM OUTGOINGS out
         JOIN incomings inc on out.ITEMID = inc.itemId
WHERE out.ITEMID = 8
  AND inc.itemId = 8 -- optional
```

Comment: cara, fez o calculo, mas não agrupou os items. coloquei o group by para tentar juntar, mas não rolou. alguma outra sugestão.

Comment: será que dá para colocar esses selects em uma variável e depois somar?